# Slow variation vs. slow increase

Tags: real-analysis, terminology

Assume that all functions in this question are defined on the interval $x\in[a,\infty)$ for some $a\in{\mathbb R}$. (The value of $a$ is assumed to exist, but need not be the same for every function below.)

J. Karamata introduced [slowly varying functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_varying_function) as follows:

**Definition:** A function $L(x)>0$ is called *slowly varying* if for any $\lambda>0$ we have
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}{L(\lambda x)\over L(x)} = 1. \tag{1}
$$

R. Jakimczuk introduced [functions of slow increase](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL13/Jakimczuk/jakimczuk8.html) as follows:

**Definition:** Suppose that $f(x)>0, \ \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$, and there exists a continuous derivative $f'(x)>0$. The function $f(x)$ is of *slow increase* if 
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} {f'(x) \over f(x)/x} = 0. \tag{2}
$$

Let ${\mathbb L}$ be the set of all slowly varying functions, and
let ${\mathbb J}$ be the set of all functions of slow increase.

**Prove or disprove this conjecture${}^*$:** if $f\in{\mathbb L}, \ f'(x)>0$, and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$, then $f\in{\mathbb J}$.

${}^*$ As shown in Daniel's answer, this conjecture is false. A correct version would require an additional condition on $f'(x)$ (see comments), for example:

*If $f\in{\mathbb L}, \ f'(x)>0$ is decreasing, and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$, then $f\in{\mathbb J}$.*

*If $f\in{\mathbb L}, \ f'(x)>0$ is non-increasing, and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$, then $f\in{\mathbb J}$.*

(In the other direction, if $f\in{\mathbb J}$, then $f\in{\mathbb L}$ -- that is, ${\mathbb J}\subset{\mathbb L}$. See [this linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2357838/if-f-is-a-function-of-slow-increase-then-f-is-slowly-varying).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conjecture is wrong, one needs more regularity to guarantee $f \in \mathbb{J}$.

Consider a piecewise linear function $g \colon \bigl[\frac{1}{2}, +\infty\bigr) \to [0,+\infty)$ that has a triangular spike of area $1/n$ and height $n$ centred at each integer $n$. Let

$$f(x) = 1 + \int_{1/2}^x e^{-t} + g(t)\,dt.$$

Then $f'$ is strictly positive, and $f$ is slowly varying with $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} f(x) = +\infty$. $f\in \mathbb{L}$ since there is a constant $K$ such that $\lvert f(\lambda x) - f(x)\rvert \leqslant K + \lvert \log \lambda\rvert$ for every $\lambda > 0$, whence

$$\frac{f(\lambda x) - f(x)}{f(x)} \to 0.$$

But, $f(x)/x \to 0$, while $f'(x)$ becomes arbitrarily large, hence

$$\limsup_{x\to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)/x} = +\infty.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel! If we modify the Conjecture by adding one more condition, $f'(x)$ is decreasing, then will the modified Conjecture be true?

Comment: Not if $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} f'(x) = L > 0$. Then we also have $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{x} = L$ and hence $\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)/x} \to 1$. If $f'(x) \to 0$, I think one can also arrange that $\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)/x} \geqslant \varepsilon > 0$, but I need to check that.

Comment: I thought that if $f\in{\mathbb L}$ and $f'$ is decreasing, then necessarily  $f'$ is decreasing to zero. (Otherwise, if $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} f'(x) = L > 0$, then $f$ will be "almost linear" for large $x$, hence not slowly varying.)

Comment: Ah, you're right with that. I forgot about the slowly varying bit. Then $f'$ non-increasing may suffice. I need to think about that.

Comment: @Alex Yep, additionally demanding that $f'$ is non-increasing suffices. Pick $0 < \lambda < 1$. Then by monotonicity of $f'$ and the mean value theorem we have $$\frac{f(x) - f(\lambda x)}{(1-\lambda)x} = f'\bigl(x(1-\vartheta\lambda)\bigr) \geqslant f'(x),$$ where $0 < \vartheta < 1$, and hence we have $$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)/x} \leqslant \frac{1}{1-\lambda} \frac{f(x) - f(\lambda x)}{f(x)}$$ and the right hand side tends to $0$.