# Prove that the condition $\sum_{n \ge 1} n^tL(n)P(|X|>n^{1/r})< \infty$ is equivalent to $E[|X|^{(t+1)r}L(X)]<\infty$.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Prove that the condition $\sum_{n \ge 1} n^tL(n)P(|X|>n^{1/r})< \infty$ is equivalent to $E[|X|^{(t+1)r}L(X)]<\infty$.

Where $X$ is some random variable and $L(\cdot)$ is a non-negative, non-decreasing continuous function of slow growth [(also called slowly varying functions)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_varying_function).

I tried re-arranging terms of the terms of the series but couldn't make them look similar, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you add the definition of slow growth? Thanks!

Comment: @air they're also called slowly varying functions, for all $a>0$, $L(ax)/L(x)$ goes to $0$ as $x$ goes to infinity

Answer (score 1):

I will prove this result only for $L(t) = \log(t)$. Hopefully, the basic idea generalizes. I will also assume that $r, t>0$.

Let $Y=|X|^r$. By the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$$ Y^{t+1}L(Y) = \int_0^{\infty} \mathbf 1\{Y > u\} \left( (t+1)u^t L(u) + u^{t+1}L'(u)\right)du.$$

Hence by Fubini:
$$ \mathbb E[Y^{t+1}L(Y)] =  \int_0^{\infty}  \mathbb P[Y > u] \left( (t+1)u^t L(u) + u^{t+1}L'(u)\right)du \;\;\;(*).$$

We can conclude by noting the following facts:

1. $\mathbb P[Y >u] = \mathbb P[|X| >u^{1/r}]$
2. $L(Y) = rL(|X|)$
3. $u^{t+1}L'(u) = u^t$ and so the 2nd summand on the RHS of $(*)$ will be negligible compared to the 1st.
4. Standard results bounding integrals by Riemann sums.

Comment: thanks very much, I will see how I can generalize observations 2. and 3. to more general slowly varying functions and post here if I find something.

Comment: Sounds great. Observations 3 seems related to this post (which however proves a result in the other direction): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2357838/if-f-is-a-function-of-slow-increase-then-f-is-slowly-varying